# Neo4j - Replace multiple values in string list property with single value

Tags: neo4j, properties, contains

I have a node, with a list property.  The list can contain multiple similar values:

["something one", "something two", "another property", "something three"]

My goal is to find all of the nodes that have one or more 'something ...' value(s) in the property and replace all of the 'something ...' properties with the single property value 'something'.

["something", "another property"]

As I see it there are two problems:

1. Locate all of the nodes where the list property contains 'something'.
2. Replace all single or multiple instances of 'something ...' with the single 'something' value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This logic may work for you:

```
MATCH (n:Foo)
WHERE ANY(x IN n.list WHERE x STARTS WITH 'something')
SET n.list =
  REDUCE(s = ['something'], t IN n.list | CASE WHEN t STARTS WITH 'something' THEN s ELSE s + t END )
```

It uses the [REDUCE](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/functions/list/#functions-reduce) function to create a list with 'something' as the first element and without any other 'something...' elements.

Comment: Brilliant!  This looks like just what I needed.  Thanks for introducing me to REDUCE.

Answer (score 0):

try ..

```
match (n:foo} where n.property<>replace(n.property,'something,'') return n
```

The replace function in Neo4j uses regex, which is base on traversals. So this is quite efficient even with large strings.

If you use the split function, you can get a String[] and process the individual elements.